# Factory method by type name

Tags: c#, oop

I need to create factory method that takes type name and params. Example:

`ShapeFactory.CreateShape("Circle", new Object[] { 4 }) ShapeFactory.CreateShape("Rectangle", new Object[] { 3, 5 })`

All shapes derived from BaseShape with method .GetName(); I cannot put together, how to use GetName method to get shape name and create it by string parameter.

Factory method interface:

```
public static object CreateShape(string shape, object[] parameters)
{
    // realization for example
    switch (shape)
    {
      case "Rectangle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 2) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Rectangle(TryCastToFloat(parameters[0]), TryCastToFloat(parameters[1]));

      case "Circle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Circle(TryCastToFloat(parameters[0]));

      case "Square":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Square(TryCastToFloat(parameters[0]));

      default:
        throw new UnsupportedShapeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point of this. Why do you need this method? Why can't you just create Circles, Rectangles, and Squares directly?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Why be strongly typed when you can be stringly typed?

Comment: I agree with @ControlAltDel here. This method seems like an abstraction that is only going to create more problems. Something safer like `ShapeFactory.CreateSquare` would allow you to ignore the string weirdness which also removes the possibility of getting a `UnsupportedShapeException`. It also means you don't get a runtime exception if the calling code passes in the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: Generally, if you are using `object`, you should really, really know what you are doing, because you are getting rid of the type safety C# is designed to provide.

Comment: Is `GetName` a static method on the class, or an instance method on objects?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to construct the object the way you want. If all you have is a string value at run time, a `switch` statement like this is probably (unfortunately) your best option. But we can improve it somewhat:

```
public static BaseShape CreateShape(string shape, params float[] parameters)
{
    switch (shape)
    {
      case "Rectangle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 2) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Rectangle(parameters[0], parameters[1]);
        break;
      case "Circle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Circle(parameters[0]);
        break;
      case "Square":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Square(parameters[0]);
        break;
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedShapeException();
    }
}
```

Now, the result of method will be typed to use the `BaseShape`, which is an improvement over `Object`. Additionally, we're forcing the caller to ensure their arguments will cast to float. Finally, we no longer need to construct an array manually. You can instead call the method like this:

```
var circle = ShapeFactory.CreateShape("Circle", 2.0);
var rect = ShapeFactory.CreateShape("Rectangle", 3.0, 5.0);
```

We could also try generics to get even better typing:

```
public static T CreateShape<T>(string shape, params float[] parameters) where T : BaseShape
{
    switch (shape)
    {
      case "Rectangle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 2) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Rectangle(parameters[0], parameters[1]);
        break;
      case "Circle":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Circle(parameters[0]);
        break;
      case "Square":
       // if (parameters.Length != 1) throw new WrongParamCountException();
        return new Square(parameters[0]);
        break;
      default:
        throw new UnsupportedShapeException();
    }
}
```

The implementation is the same, but now you must also specify the shape as a type argument when calling:

```
var circle = ShapeFactory.CreateShape<Circle>("Circle", 2.0);
```

The advantage here is the resulting `circle` variable really is typed as a `Circle`. The downside is you have to know how call the method *at compile time*, rather than, say, just loading the shape string from a database column at run time.

Comment: If you are using the generic version, then the string parameter isn't useful any more.

Comment: It certainly is possible to do what is requested using reflection, it just isn't a good idea,

Comment: @NetMage That's what I mean by "the way you want" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `GetName` is an instance property, you can collect the sub-types of `BaseShape` and map them to their `GetName` but this requires a public constructor that takes no parameters.

```
public static class ShapeFactory {
    static Dictionary<string,Type> shapeTypeMap = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                             .GetTypes()
                             .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseShape)))
                             .ToDictionary(t => ((BaseShape)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).GetName, t => t);

    public static object CreateShape(string shape, params object[] parameters) {
        if (shapeTypeMap.TryGetValue(shape, out var shapeType))
            return Activator.CreateInstance(shapeType, parameters);
        else
            throw new UnsupportedShapeException();
    }
}
```

This is **not recommended**.